# Updates on a single document at the same time in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if the following functionality would require to be implemented as a transaction in Firestore:

**Structure:**

Assume that I have an application where two users play against each other. One game contains multiple rounds, which both players can play at the same time. Each game is represented as one document in Firestore, within this document all the rounds are stored. For the sake of simplicity, assume that the rounds only consist of two fields, player1Time, and player2Time. After a player finished their round, a cloud function is triggered which updates their time (depending on the player being player1 or player2). Additionally, there is a field called state (type number) that needs to be increased every time a player finishes their round (twice per round):

**Question:**

Since both players can play a round at the same time, there is a chance that a write operation to a document is applied at the same time. These write operations do not "collide" because they write to different fields within that document (either player1Time or player2Time, which are both stored in the same array), and the field state is updated by using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment`. Would there be any problems with not writing this logic as a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additionally, there is a field called state (type number) that needs to be increased every time a player finishes their round (twice per round).

Since you say that there may be a chance that both users can finish the game at the exact same time, but you update different fields, then you don't need to use a transaction.

On the other hand, the increment operation that you're using increments the `state` field atomically. The difference between a transaction and the increment operation is that the latter doesn't read the value of the field when it performs the update.

So in your use case, there is no need for any transactions.